# How does a weight connected to a string over a pulley pulling a cart apply force onto the cart?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram, string

How does the mass hanging down on the bottom (Assuming frictionless environment) apply a pull force to the car? How does the weight of the object transfer to the string (tension force and maybe the pulley does something?) which pulls the car?

[image: Weight_Pulley_Cart]

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ it?

Comment: The pulley rotates...? You need to clarify why you have an issue with this.

Comment: Basically, I am wondering how the vertical force gets transformed into a horizontal one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if the following diagram is helpful:

[image]

There is a force from the pulley on the string - that is what allows the tension to "turn the corner" so the force from the weight (which is downwards) is turned into a horizontal force (tension that can pull the cart).

Comment: Is the force applied by the pulley distributed evenly across the two ends of the string?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The force is not "across the ends of the string", it is "on the string".

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks! Last question - Is the weight of the item simply just the same as the force of the pull on the car?

Comment: If there is no friction in the pulley, then yes.